# How would one characterize a PR-complete language?

Tags: computability-theory, computational-complexity

The complexity class $PR$ is the set of all formal languages that can be decided by a primitive recursive function.  Is there any language $l$ known to be complete for this class, i.e., for every language in $PR$ there is a primitive-recursive reduction from it to $l$?

Perhaps this notion is trivial, or it trivially does not exist (thus it is not worth appearing explicitly in the literature, at least not in this form) and I am simply thinking too hard about it.  A reasonable candidate for $l$ would seem to be {<$p,x,y$> | $p$ is an encoding of a p.r. function which maps $x$ to $y$}, but that set would not appear to be itself primitive recursive, as there is no universal p.r. function to accept it.

Comment: Yes, this notion is trivial. Every nonempty PR language with nonempty complement is PR-complete under primitive recursive reductions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me consider another reformulation of the question which makes it nontrivial: is there a PR-complete language under *polynomial-time* reductions?

The answer is no, since (apart from the first few levels) each level of the Gregorczyk hierarchy is closed under polynomial reductions. Thus, if the alleged complete language were in $\mathcal E_n$, then it would follow that PR collapses to $\mathcal E_n$, however the Grzegorczyk hierarchy is known to be strictly increasing. Alternatively, one may use the time-hierarchy theorem: if $L$ were a PR-complete language, then $L$ is decidable in time eventually bounded by $A(k,n)$ for a constant $k$, where $A$ is the Ackermann function. Then every language polynomially reducible to $L$ is decidable in time $A(k,n^c)$, which is asymptotically (much) less than $A(k+1,n)$. By the time hierarchy theorem, there exists a language decidable in time $A(k+1,n)$ (and therefore primitive recursive) which is not polynomially reducible to $L$.

The same argument applies to PR-completeness under reductions whose complexity is restricted to any fixed level of the Gregorczyk hierarchy instead of polynomial time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mean the definition of universality that you wrote, because it trivializes the question. The language $\{0\}$ is universal in this sense, because you can reduce any PR language $X$ to it by the PR function that sends $x$ to 0 if $x\in X$ and to 1 otherwise.

Let me therefore switch to a more standard notion of universality: For every PR language $X$ there is an index $e$ such that, for all $x$, we have $x\in X$ iff $(e,x)\in l$.  (Here  $(e,x)$ refers to your favorite (PR) pairing function.)  No PR language $l$ can satisfy this definition because $(x,x)\notin l$ is PR and has no index $e$.  (If it had an index $e$ then it would contain $(e,e)$ iff it doesn't contain it.)

The phenomenon here is quite general: A class of languages, closed under negation, and with other milder closure properties (like a pairing function) can't contain a universal example.

Comment: Thank you. I was well aware of the non-existence of universal p.r. functions by the diagonalization argument; I think my confusion here is coming from trying to see PR as a complexity class and attempting to use complexity-preserving reductions to characterize it.